# Pause and Resume Macro

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I've coded a excel macro which feeds data from different columns and same row to a website. Once all the data is put in website's fields, there is a submit button which needs to be clicked. This same process has to happen for each row. Loop is there but the requirement is to click the

> SUBMIT BUTTON

manually not with codes.

Since macro loops for all the rows, how can I pause it and let the user click on submit button and when post submitting webpage is ready, resume the loop again. 
Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you.

(1) invoking a `MsgBox` will pause the code.

User can be prompt to click `Ok` on the `MsgBox` for the code to continue to run, hence before click Ok, they can click submit on the website. When the website is ready for user input again, then `Ok` button can be click. Drawback is they have to do two clicking instead of one, and user need to know when to click it (not too early before website is ready). Anyway the good thing is deploying this is just peace of pancake.

(2) add an event listener

Generally like this

```
Dim ResumeEventListener as Boolean
ResumeEventListener = False

Do While Not ResumeEventListener 
    ResumeEventListener = ...'<some code to set it to true when the website is ready>
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Drawback... hmm... not easy but worth it :)

Comment: For MsgBox, I've already added it. But I want to work it natural way. When it's done feeding values, pause the macro... Now can we do any get even like the moment submit button is pressed it resumes the macro...